# C++ Why does Placement New require an STL header?

Tags: syntax, stl, header-files, specifications

It seems no other syntax based, opposed to template based, feature requires a header. None of the other new/delete related features require it.
What odd situation makes this feature require its own header?

This has been very inconvenient for me since in my circumstance I can't include any of the STL; while the single header `<new>` with recursion includes >~20k lines of the standard libraries.

Comment: Placement new was around even before STL was conceived.  Have you tried it without <new>?

Comment: @cup yeah this is known to be a requirement, the question is so strange it seems like the situation is incorrect

Comment: So does it build without <new>?  Which compiler are you using?

Comment: `typeid` is "syntax-based" but requires a header.

Comment: A workaround to this - move assignment . Its weird to have to pass {} as an arg to any function which performs a construction, but also shows whats happening more explicitly.